# Xamarin Forms PCL Consuming WCF does not always return a value

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a simple WCF service that is validating a login and return an object representing a user.

It is being run with a Xamarin Forms PCL project.
When I click the login button, the returned object returns null the first time, but when pressing a second time it returns the user object.

The object is being created in the async functions on completed method.

I am not quite sure what I am missing.

Here are pieces of code to help clarify.

Thanks for any and all assistance!

The function called by clicking the button...

```
private void buildLoginUser(string strUserName, string strPassword)
    {
        if (strUserName == null || strPassword == null) {
            strResult = "Please Enter User Name and Password.";
            DisplayAlert("Alert",strResult,"OK"); 
        } else {

            //IF USERNAME AND PASSWORD RECEIVED VALIDATE AGAINST DB
            //cl.ValidateUserAsync (strUserName, strPassword);
            //strResult = strUserRole;

            BuildClientService bcs = new BuildClientService ();
            //AuthenticateUser au = new AuthenticateUser ();

            TDMSClient cl = new TDMSClient ();
            cl = bcs.InitializeServiceClient();
            cl.ValidateUserAsync(strUserName, strPassword);
            //au.AuthenticateUserLogin (strUserName, strPassword, cl);
            //DisplayAlert("New User", lu.FullName, "OK");
            if (lu.FullName == null || lu.FullName == "") {
                DisplayAlert ("Alert", "NULL", "OK");
            } else {
                DisplayAlert ("Alert", lu.FullName, "OK");
            }

        }
```

The code that builds the user object...

```
public class BuildClientService
{
    public static readonly EndpointAddress EndPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://wcf.thompsoncs.net/TDMS.svc");

    public string strUserRole = "";

    BasicHttpBinding binding = CreateBasicHttp();

    private static BasicHttpBinding CreateBasicHttp()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding
        {
            Name = "basicHttpBinding",
            MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
        };
        TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
        binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
        binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
        return binding;
    }

    public TDMSClient InitializeServiceClient(){
        TDMSClient cl = new TDMSClient();

        cl = new TDMSClient (binding, EndPoint);
        cl.ValidateUserCompleted += clOnValidateUserCompleted;

        return cl;
    }

    private void clOnValidateUserCompleted(object sender, ValidateUserCompletedEventArgs validateUserCompletedEventArgs)
    {
        TDMS.Login.lu = validateUserCompletedEventArgs.Result;

    }
}
```

Thanks! I changed the code and I am now getting a UI thread error...
uikit consistency error you are calling a uikit method that can only be invoked from the ui thread.

```
private async void buildLoginUser(string strUserName, string strPassword)
    {
        if (strUserName == null || strPassword == null) {
            strResult = "Please Enter User Name and Password.";
            DisplayAlert("Alert",strResult,"OK"); 
        } else {

            //IF USERNAME AND PASSWORD RECEIVED VALIDATE AGAINST DB

            BuildClientService bcs = new BuildClientService ();

            TDMSClient cl = new TDMSClient ();
            cl = bcs.InitializeServiceClient();

            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => cl.ValidateUserAsync(strUserName, strPassword));

            await task.ContinueWith (e => {
                if (lu.FullName == null || lu.FullName == "") {
                    DisplayAlert ("Alert", "NULL", "OK");
                } else {
                    DisplayAlert ("Alert", lu.FullName, "OK");
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your method into an `Async` method.

At the moment your `ValidateUserAsync` method returns straight away meaning that `lu.FullName` is null or empty.

To turn your method into an async method add the word `aync` to the method and `await` to the async line you would like to await.

```
private async void buildLoginUser(string strUserName, string strPassword)
{
    if (strUserName == null || strPassword == null) {
        strResult = "Please Enter User Name and Password.";
        DisplayAlert("Alert",strResult,"OK"); 
    } else {

        //IF USERNAME AND PASSWORD RECEIVED VALIDATE AGAINST DB
        //cl.ValidateUserAsync (strUserName, strPassword);
        //strResult = strUserRole;

        BuildClientService bcs = new BuildClientService ();
        //AuthenticateUser au = new AuthenticateUser ();

        TDMSClient cl = new TDMSClient ();
        cl = bcs.InitializeServiceClient();
        await cl.ValidateUserAsync(strUserName, strPassword);
        //au.AuthenticateUserLogin (strUserName, strPassword, cl);
        //DisplayAlert("New User", lu.FullName, "OK");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lu.FullName)) {
            DisplayAlert ("Alert", "NULL", "OK");
        } else {
            DisplayAlert ("Alert", lu.FullName, "OK");
        }

    }
}
```

[Here's some more information and examples on Async/Await](http://www.dotnetperls.com/async)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but I get an error stating that "cannot await 'void' expression." 

The proxy for the WCF creates a void expression for this functions.